# How to change property for UI Element from another c# file?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I have a program with MainWindow.xaml, MainWindow.xaml.cs, and Helper.cs files. All the UI is in the .xaml file and can only be accessed from the .xaml.cs file. But now I want to change the text in a TextBox in the MainWindow.xaml file from the Helper.cs file, which is completely separate.

I've tried creating a function in MainWindow.xaml.cs to do that:

```cs
public void SetRNrInfoText(string value)
{
    this.RNrInfoTextBox.Text = value;
}
```

or

```cs
public string RNrInfoText
{
    get { return this.RNrInfoTextBox.Text; }
    set { this.RNrInfoTextBox.Text = value; }
}
```

In Helper.cs file, I use:

```cs
public static void searchByRNR()
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.SetRNrInfoText("new text"); 
}
```

However, when I try to call this searchByRNR function, nothing happens. In the .xaml file, "x:FieldModifier" is set to "public".

For now, the only idea I have is to make Helper return a dictionary or an array, and then in MainWindow, set all the values to certain textboxes, but I don't really like that idea.

So the question is, can I somehow change the property of a .xaml element in another .cs file, or is it not possible?"

Comment: You didnt include the code where you call the searchByRNR function, this is the crucial part. you create a new instance of MainWindow thus nothing happens.

Comment: Generally, you would do this with MVVM style. Have you considered a ViewModel class and use the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();` creates a new instance of the `MainWindow` class which is not what you want.

You need to get a reference to the already existing instance of the `MainWindow` in your `Helper` class somehow.

The easiest way to do this is probably to change the modifier of the `m_window` field in `App.xaml.cs` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71440820/7252182).

You can then get a reference to the window in your `Helper` class like this:

```
public static void searchByRNR()
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = (Application.Current as App)?.m_window as MainWindow; 
    mainWindow.SetRNrInfoText("new text"); 
}
```