# Printing XAML window that isn't open

Tags: c#, winui-3

Piggy backing off of this question and solution, I would like to print a XAML rendered page that's used only for printing, for example, an invoice. If I am on one screen, is it possible in WINUI3 right now to print a window that isn't visible?

The other problem being that the print only grabs what's on the screen, nothing more if you need to scroll to see the rest of the window. For example, 100 lines on an invoice.

[How to retrieve the window handle of the current WinUI 3 MainWindow from a page in a frame in a NavigationView control on the MainWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71432263/how-to-retrieve-the-window-handle-of-the-current-winui-3-mainwindow-from-a-page/71440820#71440820)

Comment: If the window hasn't been shown, no elements in it have been initialized so there will be nothing to print.